# When Is ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy Required?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I don't think I've been able to find a definitive answer on this, so I'll ask it here.  When is a ScriptManager (or ScriptManagerProxy in the case of using a ScriptManager on a Master Page) needed?

For example, let's say that I have a ScriptManager on a MasterPage:

1. If I have a Web Content Form that contains an UpdatePanel, does it need a ScriptManagerProxy?
2. If I have a Web Content Form that contains a User Control and that User Control has an UpdatePanel in it, does the User Control need a ScriptManagerProxy?
3. If I have a Web Content Form that contains an UpdatePanel and a UserControl that also contains an UpdatePanel, does the Web Content Form and/or the User Control require a ScriptManagerProxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ScriptManagerProxy enables a content page to pass references to the ScriptManager placed on its ASP.NET master page.

Here is an asp.net video:
http://www.asp.net/Learn/ajax-videos/video-95.aspx

Thanks

Joe