# Master page - Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ajax toolkit in my project. My project is having a master page and i am inheriting this master page in my web pages.I am using Script manager on every page but now requirement came to display a real time clock also on the master page.I had written the code using Timer to display real time clock on master page but i am getting error "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page. ".

How to fix this problem as i don't want to remove script manager from the webpages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use only one `ScriptManager` per page

But if you need to use the functionality provided by the `ScriptManager` for example to register custom scripts (this is really useful when you are creating server controls or working with content pages), there is one approach.

Use the `<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" />` server control instead

From MSDN:

> Enables nested components such as content pages and user controls to add script and service references to pages when a ScriptManager control is already defined in a parent element.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx)

For more info:

- [When Is ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy Required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312397/1268570)

Answer (score 0):

well the message is clear enough, have the script manager defined in the master page and remove it from all pages using that master page.