# Dymamically populated checkbox remembers previous selections

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, checkboxlist

I have to dynamically populate a checkbox inside an update panel in a Sharepoint site.
The problem is that eventhough i clear the selections after a button is clicked,the checkbox somehow remembers the previous selections and and shows checkbox.items[i].selected as true even for the previous selections
This issue is resolved if i remove the update panel.However i cant remove the update panel coz the whole page reloads every time a selection is made
Below is my code

```
                <div align="left">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True"  >
                <ContentTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBoxList    BackColor="White"  AutoPostBack="true"   ID="cbHideTabs" 
                        runat="server"  isCheckable="true" ForeColor="#0072bc" Width="300px" >
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>

                    <input type ="button"    Visible ="true" ID="HideShowTabButton" value="HideShowTab" title="HideShowTab" runat="server"   style="background-color: #0072bc; color: #FFFFFF;" enableviewstate="False" />   

            </ContentTemplate>
                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </div>
     </asp:Panel>

        <br />

        <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" Enableviewstate="false" runat="server" CommitProperty="value"
           PopupControlID="Panel1" 
            Position="Bottom" TargetControlID="ShowHideLabel">
        </asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code which you are using for Clearing the selection.

I modified your code and its working for me.

Code for aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="UpdateCheckbox._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <div>
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <asp:updatepanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkAll"    BackColor="White"  AutoPostBack="true"   
                        runat="server"  isCheckable="true" ForeColor="#0072bc" Width="300px" >
                       <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="HideShowTab" runat="server" OnClick="Clear_Click"  style="background-color: #0072bc; color: #FFFFFF;" enableviewstate="False" />

            </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:updatepanel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code in vb.net

```
Protected Sub Clear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        chkAll.ClearSelection()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Pushpendra, i am using the below code to clear my textbox and close the popupextender `cbHideTabs.ClearSelection(); PopupControlExtender1.Cancel();`  Also I cant add a scriptmanager like u did because it is already added in another user control used on the same page,and i suppose we can use only one script manager per page.

Comment: Yes, very true Script manager can have only one instance on the page else you will get error:

Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

However the better option I would sugget you to move the Script manager to the master page.

Comment: But the issue still exists.Do u think it is because of script manager only.Also since this a sharepoint site page I dont understand what you mean by a master page.

Comment: Can you share the code of Page_Load event. Have you cheked for !IsPostback. It can be the culprit.

No its not because of Script Manager. The only condition for Script Manager is that it must be present on the page before using any Ajax controls.



I think you are using the default master page. For more info on sharepoint master page do a google search after the issue is fixed.

Comment: My loading the checkbox is slightly more complex than just checking `!IsPostback` . But rest assured i am populating the checkbox only once during page load and i clear the selections once the button is clicked.I have also tried clearingout the listitems once the button is clicked and populating the checkbox again .But still the problem exists.

Comment: Are you able to get the only the checked checkboxes at runtime.
It happens many times that we are not checking for postback in pageload and everytime the page is loaded the contols are rebinded.

Comment: If you need to use Script Manager more than once you can go for Script Manager Proxy.

http://www.aspxcode.net/how-to-using-ajax-asp-net.aspx?Controls=ScriptManagerProxy


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312397/when-is-scriptmanager-scriptmanagerproxy-required